# Сессия в YII

Tags: сессия, yii, php

Странноe поведение сессии,

Если ничего не делать, сессия не работает ни во вью, ни в контроллере ( public function actionTest()), но если написать Yii::app()->getSession();, начинает работать во вью. В контроллере так и не работает, помогите, пожалуйста!

Конфиг сессий:

```
    'session' => array (

    'sessionName' => 'PHPSESSID',

    'class'=> 'CDbHttpSession',

   // 'autoCreateSessionTable '=> 'true'  ,

    'connectionID' => 'db',

    'sessionTableName' => 'SessionTable',

    'useTransparentSessionID'   =>($_POST['PHPSESSID']) ? true : false,

    'cookieMode' => 'allow',

    'timeout' => 300

)
```

Comment: не понятно как вы его используете..
Yii::app()->getSession(); возвращает CDbHttpSession с ним и работаете

Comment: Пробую сначала $_SESSION['test']='XXXX';
потом удаляю и вывожу print_r($_SESSION);

Comment: Забудьте про $_SESSION, у вас фреймворк неплохо работает с сессиями используйте его.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка, делаю тоже самое, только вместо $_SESSION использую Yii::app()->session; И все равно не работает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сохранить в сессию

```
Yii::app()->session->add("test", $test);
```

Получить из сессии

```
 $test = Yii::app()->session->get("test");
```

В конфиге у Вас указано хранение в БД в таблице SessionTable. Проверьте, сохраняется ли туда сессия

Comment: А как быть, если я хочу получить весь массив?

Проверил, сохраняется.

Comment: $session= Yii::app()->session->toArray()
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession#toArray-detail

Comment: Читайте документацию, там все есть :-)